# HTTPS not working for a specific site in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, https

I need to browser a https site in IE(doesn't work with other browser due to VB script's). Everything works fine in Windows 7 but in windows XP(SP2) i can open the site in Firefox but it doesn't work with IE it says "Page cannot be displayed!" what could be the problem?

EDIT: i am using IE 8 in windows xp sp2 but still it shows the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The web admin may have disabled the ciphers used by IE6 that have vulnerabilities, to increase security.  I have done this myself on some e-commerce websites which no longer get many IE6 visitors any more.

You can check which cipher suites the HTTPS website supports using [this online test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).  Look at what it says for IE6 under 'Handshake Simulation'.

You can also check the ones your browser supports [using this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html).

This answer assumes you are using IE6 and if that is not the case you can probably disregard it.  If you are using IE6 the solution is to upgrade to IE7 or IE8.

Comment: Nice. One aside: have you inferred that the OP is using IE6 from the Windows XP version?

Comment: @Arjan: I thought that was stated in the question?  You meant as opposed to the Windows 2000 version?  I think XP would be more likely even though he didn't mention it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... The question mentions *some* IE on XP, your answer mentions IE6. So, I wondered why you think the question asker is specifically using IE6. :-)

Comment: @Arjan: Oh I see what you mean.  It has been so long since I used XP/2003 that I forgot you could use IE up to version 8 on XP, or whatever.  However, I still think IE6 is likely as it is IE6 that has cipher vulnerabilities which people are disabling these days to get a high security grade on that test (RC4, IIRC).

Comment: @paradroid even after upgrading to IE 8 i face the same issue!!

Comment: @problemguy, you're not giving us much information to go by. Like: what result did that website that paradroid linked to give you? Which website are you having trouble with?